# Set timeout "globally" (for all operations) in Vert.x router

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a (very) small **Vert.x 3.x** application. I'm trying to set a timeout for all the routes in one router:

```
public class ServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  private void bootstrap(Handler<AsyncResult<HttpServer>> next) {
    final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(TimeoutHandler.create(3000)); // 3 seconds
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

    // [start] REST API
    router.get("/api/v1/phones/:number").handler(/*this::handleGenerateCombinations*/);
    // [end] REST API

    router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
    vertx.createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(router::accept)
        .listen(config().getInteger("http.port", 9080), next::handle);
  }

  private void done(AsyncResult<HttpServer> http, Future<Void> future) {
    if (http.succeeded()) {
      future.complete();
    } else {
      future.fail(http.cause());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> future) {
    bootstrap(http -> done(http, future));
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }
}
```

...but whenever I execute the `handleGenerateCombinations` method (I'm making it to take more than 3 seconds to cpmplete) it never times-out but report in the console:

```
Dec 27, 2015 io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 3167 ms, time limit is 2000
Dec 27, 2015 io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 5952 ms, time limit is 2000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
. . .
```

I'm not sure where those two seconds are coming from, but I think `router.route().handler(TimeoutHandler.create(3000));` is not doing the trick.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you are blocking the event loop that is why the timeout is not triggered.

Since it's reactive you shouldn't block the event loop. If the `handleGenerateCombinations` requires more time then you should use a [WorkerVerticle](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#worker_verticles). With WorkerVerticle if it lasts longer than 3 seconds you will get a timeout.

Comment: I want a time-out regardless the operation and it makes sense to have it there, in the HTTP "server"; it must be configurable somewhere. `handleGenerateCombinations` is just a method that calls (asynchronously) a "Worker Verticle" with a specified time-out for that call also...but I want to set a time-out for every HTTP request, regardless the operation

Comment: You set the timeout correctly, it just won't work if the event loop is blocked.

Comment: Weird...I thought a time-out is a "time out" for real, regardless the operation that's ongoing (or very close to that). I'll test it and accept your answer if that's the issue...I didn't know that blocking the event-loop won't trigger any time-out already set